# Is the derivative of $\{x\}$ on $(0,1)$ always equal to $1$?

Tags: solution-verification, fractional-part

Define the function $f:(0,1)\to[0,1]$ where $f(x)=\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. Am I correct in thinking that $f'(x)=1$ for $x\in(0,1)$? I'm asking because I think what I say is correct, but Mathematica 10 throws up other values, e.g.

```
N[FractionalPart'[9/10]] = 5.29432
```

**EDIT**

According to a member of the Mathematica team, they *"...agree that that result from the derivative of FractionalPart doesn't really make sense.  The symbolic derivative of FractionalPart hasn't really been implemented, so taking the numerical approximation doesn't return anything meaningful. There are developer reports on this issue so this functionality might exist in the future."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x\}=x$ on $(0,1)$ so its derivative is 1.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean f′(x)=1?

And yes you are correct in this thinking .

Comment: Yes, sorry - question updated. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 1):

That is **absolutely bizarre**.  I just confirmed your calculation in *Mathematica 9*.  Even if I crank up `WorkingPrecision`, it doesn't give the expected result.  Here is the output of

```
Plot[FractionalPart'[x], {x, 0, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 100,
     MaxRecursion -> 8, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {-2, 4}]
```

[image]

This is **clearly** incorrect.

Comment: Mathematica is great, but it does have bugs. I've found at least 5 so far in my life time of using it. From infinite summations, to sum convergence conditions, to this !! I've filed another bug report with Mathematica ;-)

Comment: Wolfram alpha miscomputes multivariable limits all the time. I think it computes the iterated limits instead of the global limit.

Comment: Looks like the Gibb's phenomena gone bonkers.

Comment: But there IS an explanation! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29329/193

Comment: @belisarius thanks for the reference:  I couldn't find it in a cursory search, hence the duplicate post in mma.se.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes searching for these things isn't easy at all

Comment: So it's down to the method used to compute the derivative. Need to be judicious with tools.